# Naming line intersection and using it later

Tags: intersections

I have drawn tangents to my ellipse, and I would like to find the intersections of those tangents and connect them into a line. I know how to make that line, but I don't know how to get those intersections as coordinates so I can use them later. The code bellow doesn't work, it does not recognise X and Y as coordinates.

Thanks for all the help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,arrows,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\clip (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\coordinate (A) at (130:2 and 1);
\coordinate (B) at (100:2 and 1);
\coordinate (C) at (40:2 and 1);

\draw[black,thick] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1);

\draw[blue,name path=tanAl] (A) -- ++ ({-2*sin(130)},{cos(130)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanAd] (A) -- ++ ({2*sin(130)},{-cos(130)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanBl] (B) -- ++ ({-2*sin(100)},{cos(100)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanBd] (B) -- ++ ({2*sin(100)},{-cos(100)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanCl] (C) -- ++ ({-2*sin(40)},{cos(40)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanCd] (C) -- ++ ({2*sin(40)},{-cos(40)});

\coordinate (X) at (intersection of tanAd and tanBl);
\coordinate (Y) at (intersection of tanBd and tanCl);

\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D,E,F,X,Y}
  \fill[black] (\p) circle (0.04);
\draw[black] ($(A)+(90:0.3)$) node{$A$};
\draw[black] ($(B)+(110:0.3)$) node{$B$};
\draw[black] ($(C)+(90:0.3)$) node{$C$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the nodes `X` and `Y` as `path`.

```
\path [name intersections={of=tanAd and tanBl,by={X}}];
\path [name intersections={of=tanBd and tanCl,by={Y}}];
```

Also you don't need the centering in `standalone` class.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,arrows,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\clip (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\coordinate (A) at (130:2 and 1);
\coordinate (B) at (100:2 and 1);
\coordinate (C) at (40:2 and 1);

\draw[black,thick] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1);

\draw[blue,name path=tanAl] (A) -- ++ ({-2*sin(130)},{cos(130)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanAd] (A) -- ++ ({2*sin(130)},{-cos(130)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanBl] (B) -- ++ ({-2*sin(100)},{cos(100)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanBd] (B) -- ++ ({2*sin(100)},{-cos(100)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanCl] (C) -- ++ ({-2*sin(40)},{cos(40)});
\draw[blue,name path=tanCd] (C) -- ++ ({2*sin(40)},{-cos(40)});

%\coordinate (X) at (intersection of tanAd and tanBl);
%\coordinate (Y) at (intersection of tanBd and tanCl);
\path [name intersections={of=tanAd and tanBl,by={X}}];
\path [name intersections={of=tanBd and tanCl,by={Y}}];

\foreach \p in {A,B,C,X,Y} % The nodes D,E,F are not defined. Removed them.
  \fill[black] (\p) circle (0.04);
\draw[black] ($(A)+(90:0.3)$) node{$A$};
\draw[black] ($(B)+(110:0.3)$) node{$B$};
\draw[black] ($(C)+(90:0.3)$) node{$C$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. How do I change the draw tangent to path (I don't want drawn tangent anymore)?

Comment: Your welcome. If I understood right your question, change `draw` command to `path`, i.e, `\path [blue,name path=tanAl] (A) -- ++ ({-2*sin(130)},{cos(130)});`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just because you asked these follow up questions in a comment under your previous question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4,eltangent/.style={insert path={%
($(#1:2 and 1)+({-2*sin(#1)},{cos(#1)})$) coordinate(et-#1-A)
--($(#1:2 and 1)+({2*sin(#1)},{-1*cos(#1)})$) coordinate(et-#1-B)}},
bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.05cm}]
\clip (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\coordinate (A) at (130:2 and 1);
\draw[black,thick] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1);
\node[label=above:$A$,bullet] at (A){};
\draw[blue,eltangent=130];
\draw[blue,eltangent=80];
\path (intersection cs:first line={(et-130-A)--(et-130-B)},second
line={(et-80-A)--(et-80-B)}) node[bullet,label=above:$I$]{};
\node[above]{$\gamma(t)=\bigl(2\,\cos(t),\sin(t)\bigr)$};
\node[below]{$\dot\gamma(t)=\bigl(-2\,\sin(t),\cos(t)\bigr)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want to draw the tangents, use

```
\path[eltangent=130];
\path[eltangent=80];
\path (intersection cs:first line={(et-130-A)--(et-130-B)},second
line={(et-80-A)--(et-80-B)}) node[bullet,label=above:$I$]{};
```

Please keep [ferahfeza's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503354/121799) the accepted one.

Comment: Okay, but I still need to name the path of intersections. I tried adding [name path=(I)] at the end, but it does not work. (Sorry for stupid questions but I'm a total beginner and in a rush)

Comment: @MocS The intersection is at `(intersection cs:first line={(et-130-A)--(et-130-B)},second
line={(et-80-A)--(et-80-B)})`. You could say `\path (intersection cs:first line={(et-130-A)--(et-130-B)},second
line={(et-80-A)--(et-80-B)})  coordinate (I);` to give it the name `I`.

Comment: @user121799 , Thank you, marmot. Recently, there have been those who have accepted my answer and then accepted the other answer, and this has happened to me often. So I deleted many of my answers. My goal on this site is to reach 10,000 rep. points. I wonder about moderation. Then I will immediately delete my account.

Comment: @ferahfeza Hi! Did you flag such posts for moderator attention? If not yet, please add a flag there if you see something that is wrong or something that is not fair. That way moderators can notice it, and it's tracked in the system what is stated and what has been done about it. Thanks!

Comment: @user121799, Thank you for your reply. All or at least some of your predictions are correct. I think this happened to you, too. Also I'm already learning, and you're my greatest teacher. You are the biggest TiKzpert in this site. I can come back when I feel ready. Best regards.

Comment: @ferahfeza It happens to many of the users. And one of the problems is that those who understand this well enough to judge who is copying from others, are rare. I guess it make more sense to have a site in which the focus is on Ti*k*Z and friends, with moderators who are willing to look at the code and see what's going on. Everyone can rename macros, so machines will not be able to detect it. (I do not think it is in the interest of the company behind all of this to be fair. They only want to attract as many users as possible and are willing to sacrifice those who insist on morale standards.)

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, Hi! I did not flag anything. It's really not necessary. Actually, I'm talking about junk. I know that the purpose of this site is to help to people. My departure does not have a negative impact on this site. There are many knowledgeable people here, including you. I don't resent anyone. I'll be in pursuit and keep learning. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: @user121799, Your idea of a site focused on Ti*k*Z is great.